# OnClick Event Management in android

Tags: android, android-button

I have a button that brings me to a view(that works),In the next view I have three buttons

**First Button:**

[image]

**Second Button:**

[image]

but pressing the button, my application is closed

```
 public class ProgramaDemoActivity extends Activity  {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    public void menu(View a){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, menu.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public void oferta(View b){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Oferta.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

I have added the activity in the manifest.

Comment: post your error log and XML

Comment: Make sure `menu` and `Oferta` Activity added in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Post your XML and register your view in onCreate. method

Comment: You need to see your logcat first.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the right path, but it works:

```
    public void menu(View a){
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    }
    public void oferta(View b){
        setContentView(R.layout.oferta);
    }
```

Comment: If you got the answer [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/). So, that we understand your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.your_btn_id);

button.setOnClickListener(listener);

OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener(){

   public void onClick(View v){
      int id = v,getId();
      if(id==R.id.your_btn_id){
       //your operation here
      }
   }

};
```

hope this helps...